# Play vs. PlayOneShot

Tags: unity, audio

For Unity `AudioSource` objects, what is the difference between the `Play` and `PlayOneShot` methods, besides their method signatures?

Is it simply that `PlayOneShot` won't stop an already playing sound from the `AudioSource`? So given a scenario where you can guarantee that a call to `AudioSource.Play()` won't occur again until its `isPlaying` boolean value is false, is there any reason to use `PlayOneShot`?

Comment: Yeah it's weird that even 2 years later, the Unity documentation still doesn't mention this!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've already identified the main difference: PlayOneShot can play multiple sounds without cutting each other off. On the flipside however that means* you can't stop the audio clip either; it'll just play all the way through, with no way to stop it early.

*I think; I can't test this at the moment, but I recall that calling Stop() after PlayOneShot() does nothing.

Comment: Just updating on @jhocking s answer. calling Stop() ***will*** stop the current clip, even if it's played using PlayOneShot()